# Refactoring object-specific logic out of the controller Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

In my controller I currently have all the functionality to produce a working ng-grid.

controller

```
app.controller('DocumentController',function($scope,DocumentService) {
  $scope.filterOptions = {
      filterText: '',
      useExternalFilter: false
  };
    $scope.totalServerItems =0;
    $scope.pagingOptions ={
        pageSizes: [5,10,100],
        pageSize: 5,
        currentPage: 1
    }
    //filter!
    $scope.dropdownOptions = [{
        name: 'Show all'

    },{
        name: 'Show active'
    },{
        name: 'Show trash'
    }];
    //default choice for filtering is 'show active'
    $scope.selectedFilterOption = $scope.dropdownOptions[1];


    //three stage bool filter
    $scope.customFilter = function(data){
        var tempData = [];
        angular.forEach(data,function(item){
            if($scope.selectedFilterOption.name === 'Show all'){
                tempData.push(item);
            }
            else if($scope.selectedFilterOption.name ==='Show active' && !item.markedForDelete){
                tempData.push(item);
            }
            else if($scope.selectedFilterOption.name ==='Show trash' && item.markedForDelete){
                tempData.push(item);
            }
        });
        return tempData;
    }



    //grabbing data
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function(pageSize, page,  searchText){
            var data;
            if(searchText){
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                DocumentService.get('filterableData.json').success(function(largeLoad){
                    //filter the data when searching
                    data = $scope.customFilter(largeLoad).filter(function(item){
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    })
                    $scope.setPagingData($scope.customFilter(data),page,pageSize);
                })
            }
            else{
                DocumentService.get('filterableData.json').success(function(largeLoad){
                    var testLargeLoad = $scope.customFilter(largeLoad);
                    //filter the data on initial page load when no search text has been entered
                    $scope.setPagingData(testLargeLoad,page,pageSize);
                })
            }
    };
    //paging
    $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
        var pagedData = data.slice((page -1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        //filter the data for paging
        $scope.myData = $scope.customFilter(pagedData);
        $scope.myData = pagedData;
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
        if(!$scope.$$phase){
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    }

    //watch for filter option change, set the data property of gridOptions to the newly filtered data
    $scope.$watch('selectedFilterOption',function(){
            var data = $scope.customFilter($scope.myData);
            $scope.myData = data;
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
            $scope.setPagingData($scope.myData,$scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,$scope.pagingOptions.pageSize);
    })
    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions',function(newVal, oldVal){
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,$scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,$scope.filterOptions.filterText);
            $scope.setPagingData($scope.myData,$scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,$scope.pagingOptions.pageSize);
    },true)


    $scope.message ="This is a message";
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'myData',
      enablePaging: true,
        showFooter:true,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        enableCellEdit: true,
        enableColumnReordering: true,
        enablePinning: true,
        showGroupPanel: true,
        groupsCollapsedByDefault: true,
        enableColumnResize: true
    }
    //get the data on page load
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
});
```

this works and pages correctly, but this means that on every controller that I wanted to use a grid I would have to re-do all those paging functions.  So then I thought about pulling out all of that grid-specific code into it's own class.

```
var NgGrid = (function(){
    function NgGrid(gridOptions){
        this.service = gridOptions.service;
        this.filterOptions = gridOptions.filterOptions;
        this.pagingOptions  = gridOptions.pagingOptions;
        this.dropdownOptions = gridOptions.dropdownOptions;
        this.selectedFilterOption = this.dropdownOptions[1];
        this.totalServerItems = 0;
        this.myData = [];
        this.customFilter = function(data,propName){
            var tempData =[];
            angular.forEach(data,function(item){
                if(this.selectedFilterOption.name === 'Show all'){
                    tempData.push(item);
                }
                else if(this.selectedFilterOption.name === 'Show active' && !item[propName]){
                    tempData.push(item);
                }
                else if(this.selectedFilterOption.name === 'Show trash' && item[propName]){
                    tempData.push(item);
                }
            })
        }
        this.getPagedDataAsync = function(pageSize, page, searchText){
            var data;
            if(searchText){
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                //filter the data when searching
                this.service.get('filterableData.json').success(function(data){
                    data = this.customFilter(data).filter(function (item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    this.setPagingData(this.customFilter(data),page,pageSize);
                })
            }
            else{
                this.service.get('filterableDat.json').success(function(largeLoad){
                    var filtered = this.customFilter(largeLoad);
                    this.setPagingData(filtered,page, pageSize);
                })
            }
        }
        this.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
            var pagedData = data.slice((page-1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
            this.myData = this.customFilter(pagedData);
            this.myData = pagedData;
            this.totalServerItems = data.length;
            if($scope.$$phase){
                $scope.apply();
            }
        }
    }
    return NgGrid;
});
```

I reckoned that most of the things that I added to the scope like filterOptions and dropdownOptions could have default values in the constructor of the NgGrid object and perhaps be overwritten in the controller itself.  What I'm not sure about is

```
this.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
            var pagedData = data.slice((page-1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
            this.myData = this.customFilter(pagedData);
            this.myData = pagedData;
            this.totalServerItems = data.length;
            //right here it gets fuzzy, not even totally sure why it works
            if($scope.$$phase){
                $scope.apply();
            }
        }
```

from the DocumentController.js file I put many options related to the grid on its scope, so when I created my NgGrid `"class"` I switched out $scope for this.  But with this part, I have no idea what I should do.  Should I pass in a controller to the constructor of NgGrid as well?  Could I access the `$scope` of a controller that way?  Or, if I am only planning on using this object inside of a controller, should I say screw it, I know that there will be a $scope and $$phase available and leave my class the way it is?

Comment: Without getting into too much code review, my initial impression is that you're doing too much with controllers whereas much of the logic ought to be refactored into one or more services rather than a base controller. Keep in mind that while services are singletons, you can use them as factories which create and return objects, so you can use services in controllers which require their own object instance.

Comment: @MarcKline you are absolutely right in that I'm currently doing too much in the controller.  That's what I'm trying to fix :).  At the root of it, `my question is how can I access the scope of a controller from outside of that controller`. Specifically the $$phase code of the code

Comment: I guess I'm also critiquing the approach you're taking. I implied that you were creating a base controller, which was incorrect, but what I'm suggesting is that instead of moving the logic into a generic constructor, move it into a service ... and then set a scope variable to reference an instance of an object created by the service. If you do this, both the service and the controller will have "live" access to the data.... ie there would be no reason to pass scope around.

Answer (score 1):

Passing around scope is bad practice. And while there are useful ways of using generic constructors for creating reusable base controllers, services, etc. I don't think this case warrants working outside of Angular components.

I suggest instead that you move much of this logic and data into a one or more services. When you inject these services into a controller, you can assign objects they return to scope variables, which will provide you with the benefits of having data and methods on the controller scope while not bloating the controllers themselves.

In order to help demonstrate how this might work, I created [**this demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IgYPDxjcoB6g1jsrUlJn?p=preview) which, while it is quite generic and does not incorporate your code, should help provide a template for how you might approach your own refactoring.